# Determining the component values for Dc

Tags: transistors, dc

Draw the circuit diagram for DC and determine the component value. The transistor must be biased with :

[image]

[image]

This is my attempt to solve this

[image]

The picture bellow is the way I drew the DC circuit diagram

[image]

I would really appreciate if I could get some feedback regarding and some help on how to find R2

Comment: "The transistor", would that be Q1 or Q2?

Comment: @winny , in this case it would be both because R2 is connected to both of them

Comment: Please name the components exactly as shown in the original question, and it's not clear what those parameters are given for which transistor. For example, probably \$U{CE-A}\$ indicates the voltage across C and E terminals of the transistor A (QA or something). Also, it seems that you have created the schematics with Circuit Lab. You don't have to put a screenshot, instead you can directly put the schematics inside the question. It allows you to modify the circuit.

Comment: @Rohat Kılıç , Uce is across C and E terminals for both transistors. I tried but I need a paid membership to be able to do that

Comment: Please do not refer to two transistors as "the transistor". Please use component designators and refer to them.

Comment: A moment's thought will show that Uce cannot possibly be 8V across both transistors so you need to decide which transistor it is. How to find R2? Find the voltage at each end, giving you the voltage across it. Find the current through it. Compute R2 from these. (Then to see how bad this circuit is, recompute the working point changing Beta to 100)

Comment: @Brian Drummond, I really just wrote the question how it was, so I dont know which transistor it is . Can you please give me a brief answer on how you got R2. I have gotten  R2=660kohm but not sure

Comment: Add both that new info AND how you got there to the question.

Comment: @Brian Drummond, If you could help me I would appreciate it. I just want someone to tell me the right way so I understand the problem and not face the same problem in the future. if you can't still thank you. That is how the question was asked so I dont know which transistor to choose

Comment: Since the question says Uce.A = 8V. choose the transistor most likely to be A, and call the other one B.  My guess would be Q1. Then work out Vce for Q2 and follow my first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Some parts of your question are a bit fuzzy. Improve that next time.

Comment: thank you. How come Re is equal to 10kohm ?. Shouldn't Re= 7.3v/4mA ?

Comment: that's a fuzzy part in 1st pix

Comment: what do you mean by fuzzy part ? I can upload a better quality picture of the circuit.. Shouldn't Re= 7.3v/4mA ?

Comment: There are 2 caps and Re given as 10k, it doesn't make sense to have more current =4mA in Q1 yet Re was given if I read it OK  ...fuzzy

Comment: I see it is RL not Re so yes Re=1.8k=7.3V/4mA

Comment: thank you. I have another question regarding the same circuit if you could help. **Question** : Determine the transfer function using these values C1=10μF, C2=100μF ?

Comment: Don't you know f-3dB=1/(2piRC)

Comment: No  I don't, Could you please tell me what would be the transfer function of this circuit using these values? I will try to find similar problems after and use what I am learning

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=1%2F%282piRC%29

Comment: can you help me a bit here on the comment ? would appreciate it a lot.

Comment: Zc=1/(2pifC)  so when Zc=R you have the log asymptote breakpoint  or -3dB frequency  = 0.707 = 1/sqrt (1+1)